# c# Custom name for a txt file StreamWriter

Tags: c#, streamwriter

I need a text file named to username_currentdate.txt

```
string username = Console.ReadLine();
string place = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
string date = DateTime.Now.ToString("h:mm:ss");
StreamWriter FajlW = new StreamWriter(Path.Combine(place,username + "_" + date + ".txt"));
```

I dont get any error in Visual Studio but when i open it i get a lot.
[image]

Comment: Could you give us exception in English as text - not image?

Comment: `:` is invalid character for file name

Answer (score 1):

A filename cannot contain any of the following characters: \ / : * ? " < > |

[https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/a-filename-cannot-contain-any-of-the-following/77f8e84c-9632-44d0-a3e6-164887e7a11e](http://answer.microsoft.com)

Comment: if this answer helped you, please mark it as answer

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is the date format. [The Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file#file-and-directory-names) state:

```
Use any character in the current code page for a name, including Unicode characters and characters in the extended character set (128–255), except for the following:

    The following reserved characters:
        < (less than)
        > (greater than)
        : (colon)
        " (double quote)
        / (forward slash)
        \ (backslash)
        | (vertical bar or pipe)
        ? (question mark)
        * (asterisk)

    Integer value zero, sometimes referred to as the ASCII NUL character.

    Characters whose integer representations are in the range from 1 through 31, except for alternate data streams where these characters are allowed. For more information about file streams, see File Streams.

    Any other character that the target file system does not allow.
```

You need to pick a format that does not have a `:` in it.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that colons are not allowed in filenames (that's at least the case for Windows und UNIX systems). So try using another (allowed) seperator:

```
string date = DateTime.Now.ToString("h_mm_ss");
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because, you have given the date to format as DateTime.Now.ToString("h:mm:ss"). Instead of ':', please use any other character as ':' is not supported in the folder path.